# Using R generating categorical scatter plot

Tags: r

Hello I am trying to do scatter plot using R, new to R. example graph which I wanted looking as below image[image]

How can I obtaine this type of graph in R anyone suggest me.
my dataframe which is looking like as below

```
data = {'grp1': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.7], 'grp2': [1,1,1,1,1,0.7,0.9,0.8,0.9,1,1,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619838/plotting-scatter-plot-by-groups-in-r) this one I tried to solve but not able do

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reshape to 'long' format and create a boxplot

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
     ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value)) + 
          geom_boxplot()
```

---

Or a dot plot

```
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = name)) + 
      geom_dotplot(binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center', 
           position = position_dodge(), dotsize = 0.5) +
      theme_bw()
```

[image]

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(grp1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.7), grp2 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0.7, 0.9, 0.8, 0.9, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.In one of my group NA that values are not present in another group in that case how can run above answer

Comment: @Hemantchandrunaik Not clear.  Your example showed was in python and the lengths were not same for each column.  Can you show the `dput` for example in `R`

Comment: okay sorry for python code, I re created daframe                                                   `data = c("grp1","grp1","grp1","grp1","grp1","grp1","grp1","grp1","grp1","grp2","grp2","grp2","grp2","grp2","grp2","grp2")                 
values=c(1,1,1,1,0.7,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.9,0.8,1,0.5,1)                                                        df = data.frame(data,values)`

Comment: for above dataframe can graph can fit?

Comment: @Hemantchandrunaik With your new 'df'. `ggplot(df, aes(x= data, y = values, fill = data)) + geom_dotplot(binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center', 
            position = position_dodge(), dotsize = 0.5) +
     theme_bw()`

Comment: just asking for option in ggplot like header for a graph and I wanted hide the background bins and x axis line. is there any option in ggplot

Comment: @Hemantchandrunaik for the title, you can use `+ ggtitle('scatterplot')`

Comment: @Hemantchandrunaik you can do `ggplot(df, aes(x= data, y = values, fill = data)) + geom_dotplot(binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center',              position = position_dodge(), dotsize = 0.5) +      theme_bw() + ggtitle('scatterplot') + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())`